# Интерфейс в Delphi

Tags: delphi, интерфейс

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать интерфейс программы на языке Delphi. В общем суть такая: программа анализирует текст и находит в нем ошибки. Все найденные ошибки записываются в ListBox процедурой `Errors.Add()`, но бывают ошибки описание которых занимает ширину больше, чем ширина этого ListBox.
Делать ListBox слишком широким нецелесообразно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от этой проблемы. Например может как-то можно сделать, чтобы осуществлялся перенос слов или появилась полоса прокрутки.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для прокрутки можно использовать не TListBox, а TMemo. В нем имеется ScrollBar и вертикальный, и горизонтальный.

Впрочем, можно сделать производный клас: TListBox + ТScrollBar, я делал, правда, не в Делфи, а в Билдере.

Comment: А можно как нибудь сделать так чтобы в TListBox сообщения не выходили за границы а переносились? Хотя бы по словам(например если слово выходит за границы то все слово перенести на следующую строку).

Comment: еще попробуйте с классом поработать TStringList.

Comment: Можно, наверное. Считайте буквы, и как только, так сразу - туда знак переноса строки - бац, с пробелом или с табом, например, или без оного. Но скроллить-то все равно придется, по крайней мере, по вертикали. Так что - лучше ТMemo.

Comment: все таки разобрался с TMemo и сделал с ним. Спасибо.